# Different between memory usage in WHM/Cpanel and Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, cpan, whm

If I go to WHM and see my server's memory usage, it says that only 16% of memory is in use.
But when I connect to server using SSH and run command "free -m" then it shows that 80% is in use. Why is that? I want to know exact memory usage of all applications running like MySQL, Apache e.t.c.
How do I view that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they say, "It's Complicated".

Linux uses unused memory for disk buffering and caching.  It speeds things up.  But you may need to look at the *-/+ buffers/cache* line of ***free***.

**'ps'** can show you, for any given process, or for all processes, the ***%cpu***, ***%mem***, ***cumulative cpu-time***, ***rss*** (resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a process is using), ***size*** (*very* approximate amount of swap space that would be required if the process were to dirty all writable pages and then be swapped out), ***vsize*** (virtual memory usage of entire process (vm_lib + vm_exe + vm_data + vm_stack)), and much much more.

For any given process, you can cat /proc/$PID/status -- it's human readable -- and check out the **VmSize**, ***VmLck***, ***VmRSS***, ***VmData***, ***VmStk***, ***VmExe***, ***VmLib***, and ***VmPTE*** values, along with others...

But that's just for starters...  Processes can allocate memory but not use it.  (Memory can be allocated, but the memory pages are not created/issued until they're actually used.  That whole on-demand thing.)

Processes can map in hardware space, showing up as using a large quantity of memory that's not actually coming from system RAM.  (X-servers are known to sometimes do this.  It's some wonky stuff involved kernel drivers...)

There's the executable, which is usually a memory-mapped file.  Meaning that parts that are swapped-in are taking up RAM, but when swapped out it never takes up swapfile space.

Processes can have other memory-mapped files...

There's shared-memory libraries, where the same RAM pages are used by multiple programs concurrently.

So we have to ask, as far as memory goes, what exactly counts and what doesn't?

Comment: Hmm...it sure is complicated but why make it that way? I mean as a normal user when I look for memory usage then I expect the operating system to tell me how much actual memory is free. For these complications there should be another screen/operation. I mean by default operating system should show free memory in simple terms and there should be another command/button which will show detail like the above. Why make it so complicated in the first place?